# How can we get text node using dom4j

Tags: java, dom4j, textnode

When we parse an XML document like

```
<entry>
  Sometext
</entry>
```

using Javax.xml.Parsers.DocumentBuilder, we can always get the text node by

```
Document doc = ...
Node entry = doc.getFirstChild();
Node textNode = entry.item(0);
```

However, I wonder how can we get text node by using dom4j. It seems dom4j doesn't treat `text` as a text node.

Answer (score 0):

see [dom4j.github.io](https://dom4j.github.io/#parsing) ...it might be something alike:

```
List<Node> list = document.selectNodes("//entry");
for (Iterator<Node> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Attribute attribute = (Attribute) iter.next();
    String text = attribute.getValue();
}
```

alternative, to only select a single node in DOM:

```
Node node = document.selectSingleNode("//entry");
```

Comment: You are right but what I want here is a `Node` type text rather than a `String`. For example, when I need to parse XQuery like `//entry/text()`, I'd like to get back a list of `Node` rather than a list of `String`. Thanks!

Comment: the first line actually obtains such a list of nodes... selected by xPath. you might only need to adjust the selector; one can copy from / validate with the  browser's common F12 tools

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

```
    String xml = "<root><entry>one</entry><entry>two</entry></root>";
    Document doc = DocumentHelper.parseText(xml);
    doc.selectNodes("//entry")
        .forEach(n -> System.out.printf("%s -> %s\n", n.getClass().getSimpleName(), n.getStringValue()));
    doc.selectNodes("//entry/text()")
        .forEach(n -> System.out.printf("%s -> %s\n", n.getClass().getSimpleName(), n.getStringValue()));
```

The first `selectNodes` call prints

```
DefaultElement -> one
DefaultElement -> two
```

while the other prints

```
DefaultText -> one
DefaultText -> two
```